# A function used to find out the starting location of a tour/journey

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

A trip has the form [starting place of the trip, destination place of the trip]. You are given the trips in random order. Write a Javascript function to find out what is the starting place of the journey. Also user may enter the places visited.

Example 1:
exampleTrips := `[ [A,B], [B,C], [C,D] ]`
The trip in this example started at `"A"`.

Example 2:
exampleTrips := `[ [D,E], [F,D], [E,X] ]` 
The trip in this example started at `"F"`.

Defined an array 
Split it into two arrays, a1 and a2
find the difference b/w a1 and a2 
return remaining element from a1

```js
var a = [ ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'a'] ];

var a1 = a.map(function(tuple) {
  return tuple[0];
});

var a2 = a.map(function(tuple) {
  return tuple[1];
});

function difference(a1, a2) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (a2.indexOf(a1[i]) === -1) {
      result.push(a1[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(difference(a1, a2));
```

Comment: But you can't tell whether a point is the start or end - there's one of each, and two of the rest. You can only return the two non-repeated elements.

Comment: could `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]` be an input ? Can you meet the same point many times ?

Comment: I need only the start means only one element

Comment: What have you done so far ? Even pseudo code

Comment: @adiga i tried `code` var a = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'],['e', 'a']];
var a1 = a.map(function(tuple){
  return tuple[0];
});
var a2 =  a.map(function(tuple){
  return tuple[1];
    });
console.log(a1,a2);
console.log(difference(a1,a2));


function difference(a1, a2) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (a2.indexOf(a1[i]) === -1) {
      result.push(a1[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
} `code`

Comment: This is unreadable in comment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56165121/edit) your question

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question from next time to create a [mcve]. (You might also want to read [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Comment: @SyedSaqib - So, what is wrong with your answer? It seems to be OK (one of a number of ways of doing it). Are you looking for something more efficient?

Comment: @SimpleOne Yes ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

First, get the start and end (only non-repeated elements), then find out which one is the first element in the array:

```js
const a = [['a','b'], ['b','c'],['d','a']];
const startEnd = a.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr)).filter((e, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e));
const res = a.findIndex(([e]) => startEnd.includes(e));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You do know which is start and end as the first entry in the pair is a start point. So, in the use case you used the answer would be 'd'. I guess once you have the start and end, you can recheck to see which of the two is in 'start' position.

Comment: I see @SimpleOne. Nice technique. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Fixed that @SimpleOne - how does that look?

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar interview question, here is my answer :

```js
const exampleTrips = [ ['Cologne','Berlin'],['Munich','Cologne'],['YourPlace','Munich'] ]
const exampleTrips2 = [ ['A', 'B'], ['B','C'], ['C','D'] ] 


const trips = (array) => {
  if(!array.length) {
    return 'Please input a trip'
  }

  const start = []
  const end = []

  for(const el of array) {
    if(el.length === 2) {
      start.push(el[0])
      end.push(el[1])
    } else {
      return 'Please input a valid start and end trip'
    }
  }

  const place = start.filter((element) => end.indexOf(element) === -1)

   console.log(place[0])
   return place[0]
}



trips(exampleTrips)
trips(exampleTrips2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the question is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

You can do this in O(n) with a hash map

```js
const findStartingPoint = (trips) => {
    // create a hash map of starting points from all trips
    const tripStarts = trips.reduce((acc, trip) => {
        acc[trip[0]] = false
        return acc
    }, {}) 
    // get ending points from all trips
    const tripEnds = trips.map(trip => trip[1])
    tripEnds.forEach(end => {
        tripStarts[end] = true
    });
    // get tripStarts - tripEnds
    // I'm assuming a journey means continuous trips. This means Every start 
    // except for the journey start should be in trip ends
    let start
    Object.keys(tripStarts).forEach(tripKey => {
        if(tripStarts[tripKey] === false) {
            start = tripKey
        }
    })
    return start ? start : 'You can start your trip anywhere'
}

console.log(findStartingPoint([['Cologne','Berlin'],['Munich','Cologne'],['YourPlace','Munich']]))
console.log(findStartingPoint(
    [
        ['Cologne','Berlin'],
        ['Munich','Cologne'],
        ['YourPlace','Munich']
    ]) === 'YourPlace')

console.log(findStartingPoint(
    [ ['A','B'], ['B','C'], ['C','D'] ]) === 'A')

console.log(findStartingPoint(
    [ ['D','E'], ['F','D'], ['E','X'] ]) === 'F')

console.log(findStartingPoint(
    [ ['A','B'], ['B','C'], ['C','D'], ['D', 'A']]) === 'You can start your trip anywhere')
```